# Magento - Attribute display admin value in front end no matter what language i pick

Tags: magento, attributes

In the back-end when managing the attribute from the attribute set i show him what text to display for the languages i have (Romanian And russian are currently active and important)

http://prntscr.com/32rhrm

However in the frontend as in Romanian Language so in Russian language it will layout the text that i input for the Admin in the attribute set

http://prntscr.com/32rhxz

how do i fix it?! how do i make it show the corresponding text for the needed language?

Thank you !!!

Comment: I think this are the custom attributes are not added in to language CSV files,add it and check once.